# How to connect android application with my websit database?

Tags: java, android, spring, rest

I have already design a web site using Spring MVC. Now I want to develop an android application that able to get the client details of my web site and the interface is completely different from my web site and also has additional functions. The changes made through android application should be updated in my web site also. What is he best way to do it? Can I make my database common for both applications or I want to move into REST web services.

Comment: You'll need to explore RESTful web services for your website. Creating API endpoints in your code that your android app can send requests to. This way both, you android app and the website will work on the same database. Spring already has projects such as https://projects.spring.io/spring-hateoas/ that make it easier to create RESTful API's.

Comment: that's all up to you. There is no best way. I'd suggest `to move into REST web services`

Comment: Let me give you an example. Create a login controller, get data from model and return it in json. Don't send it to view.

Comment: I got what you say.Then  I can get the data from my web site in JSON/XML format.If I only make my web site a RESTApi can I get the details from android applications to my web site. Is it possible in both ways sending web site data to android and getting android app data to web site.Can i update the database through my android application.